# Alternative for @DisallowConcurrentExecution

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am looking for an alternative for `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`. I have seen that a `StatefulJob` is an alternative but it is deprecated.

Let's say my job class is like:

```java
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class AJob implements Job {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AJob.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("Scheduler output: " + ZonedDateTime.now().toString());
    }
}
```

Here, I want the same functionality without `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`  annotation.

Help if there is a valid alternative

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? I.e., what is wrong with the annotation?